# What is a good alternative to text files as Database for java 1.3?

Tags: java, database

I know... you must be calling me nuts by now, for using text files as databases.
If thats ok to you, certainly using java 1.3 will be enough to call me insane.

Let me explain (yes there's an excuse for that):

I work for a company that for a thousand reasons can't (or won't) upgrade to java 5 or 6 and so on...
It doesn't allow us to create/modify databases on it's DB2 systems as well.

I know... It looks like they don't wanna let us do our jobs...

Well, enough said. The point is that we are using text files to feed our 300 reports. 
300 and growing... And our servers are on the verge of breaking down...

I tried using SQLite, but could not find any connector/wrapper that would work with java 1.3...

And now I'm out of ideas...

If anyone has been through that road (and survived to tell), and could give me any piece of advise...actually, any idea, from anyone....

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that I can't install any database server. That's why I considered SQLite, 'cos it is a "serveless" database.

Comment: what are your requirements on the database? do you need a key-value store? do you want to have a query language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 1.3, ye gods, do you use punch cards as well? :)

On a serious note, [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFeatures.html) claims to support every JDK, even the prehistoric 1.1 one. Maybe that will be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of open-source embedded databases for Java that may fit your requirements:

http://java-source.net/open-source/database-engines

The big question is which (if any) of them still support Java 1.3. I suggest having a rummage around in their docs to see what you can find.

Answer (score 1):

Versions of [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html) prior to 10.3.1.4 support JDK 1.3, see the [release notes for 10.2.2.0](http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.2.2.0.html#Release%20Overview).

It's worth noting that Derby uses the same SQL dialect as DB2 with a few differences over supported data types and functions, you can see more details at [developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0409chiang/index.html)